# On a macOS computer running Catalina, is it possible to have the /Developer/ folder that used to be present since Mac Os X was born?

Tags: macos

I am running a macOS System with Catalina 10.15.6. I used to like the `/Developer/` folder in the root of the startup disk a lot, and I tend to still miss it now that under Catalina it seems not possible to have it. I have created `/Users/<user>/Developer`, but I got used to the `/Developer/` relative paths and it annoys me. Recently, I have discovered the following terminal command:

```
sudo mount -uw /
```

This seems to make possible to mount the should-be-read-only startup disk in Catalina in read/write mode. Now I succeed to create the /Developer/ folder, and :) it even has the nice legacy icon:

[image]

but unfortunately, the folder is only writable through the terminal and I could not make it work in the Finder, although I tried all I could about chmod 777 and chown user:staff on the folder. I know this question is just for the curious, but I would like a solution if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **macOS Catalina** the new way is to use `/etc/synthetic.conf` to create a *virtual symbolic link* to the *root* of the e.g. **Macintosh HD** for the target *folder*. All writeable paths must reside on the data volume, which is mounted at: `/System/Volumes/Data`

1. It **Terminal**, run the following *commands*:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -m 0777 /System/Volumes/Data/Developer
   sudo nano /etc/synthetic.conf
   ```
2. Add the following entry to `/etc/synthetic.conf`:

   ```
   Developer       System/Volumes/Data/Developer
   ```

   - Note there is a *tab* between the *columns*.
3. Save the file using: <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Close the file using: <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
5. Reboot for the changes to take effect.

**Note:** While this creates a *symbolic link* of a plain *folder*, nonetheless, if you give the target *folder*  e.g. `/System/Volumes/Data/Developer` a custom icon and then restart **Finder**, (in **Terminal** `killall Finder`), it will show the custom icon on the *symbolic link* of the target *folder*.

<sup>See: [Create custom icons for files or folders on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-custom-icons-files-folders-mac-mchlp2313/mac)</sup>

<sup>For more information see the *manual page* for `synthetic.conf`, in **Terminal**: `man synthetic.conf`</sup>

[image]

**Note:** The **Developer** *folder* icon file is located at:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/DeveloperFolderIcon.icns
```

I added the custom icon by temporarily creating a **Developer** *folder* in my **Home** *folder*, which automatically gave it the **Developer** icon, and then used **Get Info** (**⌘I**) to copy the icon to the **Get Info** for the **Developer** *folder* at: `/System/Volumes/Data/`

- **Note:** in **Finder** the **Data** *folder* will show as e.g. **Macintosh HD** when navigating to **System** > **Volumes** >.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to write the precise answer. Much appreciated, thanks.